# How to Segue to Next View Controller After LocalAuthentication Complete

Tags: ios

I have implemented a LocalAuthentication.framework into my Swift project as I am using it to authenticate for access into an app. I have my LocalAuthentication code in place but I have

```
if(success){
    // go to next view controller
}
```

And I am basically stuck here, how would I direct `ifSuccess` to move to my next view in my story board.

I have 2 basic views, one is an authenticate view with a button press to segue to next view.

Overall I'd like to know how when the button is pressed and the authentication is complete to move to the next view. Do I need a navigation controller, or what.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Create a new Segue from 1st ViewController to 2nd VC. Not from *the button* but from the VC itself (yellow object at the top of the Scene's hierarchy)
- call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` inside your if block. Pass the identifier of this new Segue